# How do I play a video over a physical object using unity and vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on my end of year project and I need some guidance. I would like to make a video play when the object is detected. I tried using an image and it worked fine, however with physical object, things do not work at all. May I get some advice on how to proceed? 
Thank you

Comment: define "do not work at all"

Answer (score 0):

If is not detecting the object you have to consider that not all objects work well with vufuria. You can check here [Object-Recognition](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Object-Recognition) for some suggestion.

Comment: hello. so what I did is: I exported my scanned object.ob as target in a database. imported it to my Unity. Then added a quad over it and added video player over the quad. Is that the correct way of playing a video over a physical object?